# Remove attribute & matched node at once

Tags: xml, xpath, command-line, xml-parsing, xmlstarlet

I try to remove **attribute** and **child node** *at once* from xml like:

```
<xml>
  <node attribute="name">
    <child>name</child>
  </node>
</xml>
```

to expected result like

```
<xml>
  <node>
  </node>
</xml>
```

depending on **child value**.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can; try using

```
xml ed -d '//node[child["name"]]/@attribute'  -d  '//node/child["name"]' file.xml
```

The first part deletes (`-d`) the `attribute` attribute of the `node` node which itself has a `child` child node with a `name` text value; the second `-d` deletes the 'child` node itself.

Comment: Matching did not work. Not only "name" containing, but all "child" nodes was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Jack, this is working solution:

```
xml ed -d  '//node[child="name"]/@attribute' -d  '//node/child[contains(text(),"name")]' file.xml
```